# python matplotlib imshow with difference lenghts in data-array

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

Is there a way to plot heat map with different row lengths using matplotlib?

like this:

```
plt.imshow( [ [1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4]])
plt.jet()
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[Desired image](http://postimg.org/image/geoa9nrxf/)

Comment: use a seperate `ishow` for each row.  Tile them using the `extent` kwarg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the desired image, I think you will want to you `plt.pcolormesh` rather than `imshow` but I may be wrong. In any case I personally would create a function to pad the array then use a mask so that `imshow` or `pcolormesh` will not plot those points. For example

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

def regularise_array(arr, val=-1):
    """ Takes irregular array and returns regularised masked array

    This first pads the irregular awway *arr* with values *val* to make 
    it of rectangular. It then applies a mask so that the padded values
    are not displayed by pcolormesh. For this reason val should not
    be in *arr* as you will loose these points.
    """

    lengths = [len(d) for d in data]
    max_length = max(lengths)
    reg_array = np.zeros(shape=(arr.size, max_length))

    for i in np.arange(arr.size):
        reg_array[i] = np.append(arr[i], np.zeros(max_length-lengths[i])+val)

    reg_array = np.ma.masked_array(reg_array, reg_array == val)

    return reg_array

data = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4]])

reg_data = regularise_array(data, val=-1)

plt.pcolormesh(reg_data)
plt.jet()
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The issue with this is you need to take care thet `val` is not in the array. You could add a simple check for this or base it on the data you are using. The for loop could probably be vectorised but I cannot work out how.